# Как задать количество строк в QLineEdit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qlineedit

Я знаю как задать максимальное количество символов в строке:

```
lineEdit.setMaxLength(31)
```

А как задать количество строк в `QLineEdit`,
чтобы в длину он был максимум **`31`** а в высоту  максимум **`15`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виджет QLineEdit - это `однострочный` текстовый редактор.

> maxLength : int
>
> Это свойство содержит максимально допустимую длину текста. Если текст слишком длинный, он обрезается до предела.
>
> Если происходит усечение, любой выделенный текст не будет выделен, позиция курсора будет установлена ​​на 0, и будет показана первая часть строки. Если редактирование строки имеет маску ввода, маска определяет максимальную длину строки. 
> По умолчанию это свойство содержит значение 32767.

> **setMaximumWidth**(int maxw)
>
> Это свойство содержит максимальную ширину виджета в пикселях. Это свойство соответствует ширине, удерживаемой свойством maximumSize. 
> По умолчанию это свойство содержит значение 16777215. 
> Примечание. Определение макроса QWIDGETSIZE_MAX ограничивает максимальный размер виджетов.

> **setMaximumHeight**(int maxh)
>
> Это свойство содержит максимальную высоту виджета в пикселях. Это свойство соответствует высоте, удерживаемой свойством maximumSize.  
> По умолчанию это свойство содержит значение 16777215.  
> Примечание. Определение макроса QWIDGETSIZE_MAX ограничивает максимальный размер виджетов.